# How to make implicits available to inner function

Tags: scala, implicit, higher-order-functions, dotty, scala-3

I would like to define implicit value in a wrapper function and make it available to inner function, so far I managed to do that by passing implicit variable from wrapper:

```
case class B()

trait Helper {
  def withImplicit[A]()(block: => A): A = {
    implicit val b: B = B()
    block
  }
}

class Test extends Helper {
  def useImplicit()(implicit b: B): Unit = {...}

  def test = {
    withImplicit() { implicit b: B =>
      useImplicit()
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to avoid `implicit b: B =>` and make `implicit val b: B = B()` available to inner function block?

Comment: Implicits are a very powerful feature, that can lead yo very complex, confusing and unmaintable code. Any reason why you want to make this? Why not simply receive a function that requires a B?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez `B` in the actual implementation code corresponds to `Toggles`  which means that `B`s are short-lived and will be removed once the feature is rolled out, therefore to reduce amount of cleanup and make implementation logic as much decoupled from Toggles as possible I chose to inject them through implicit dependency

Comment: I am not against its use in your function. But what about something like `def withImplicit[A](block: B => A): A = block(B())` and you call it like this: `Helper.withImplicit { b: B => implicit val _b: B = b; useImplicit() }`?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Hmm thanks for suggestion! Although, it doesn't look as clean as it could be

Answer (score 6):

This will be possible in Scala 3 with implicit function types (keyword `given` is instead of `implicit`)

```
case class B()

trait Helper {
  def withImplicit[A]()(block: (given B) => A): A = {
    given B = B()
    block
  }
}

class Test extends Helper {
  def useImplicit()(given b: B): Unit = {}

  def test = {
    withImplicit() {
      useImplicit()
    }
  }
}
```

https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/implicit-function-types.html

https://dotty.epfl.ch/blog/2016/12/05/implicit-function-types.html

Comment: Thank you, looks very interesting, will keep that in mind!