# Scala - how to pass implicit parameter into function (HOF)?

Tags: scala, implicit, higher-order-functions

I have a function like this:

```
def getSomething: (String, Future[String]) => String = {
    case (name, surname) if (name == "Joe", surname.map(s => s == "Doe")) => "Is ok"
}
```

But compiler said he needs `executionContext` here in `map` function. I tried to do some magic with:

```
def getSomething (implicit e: ExecutionContext): (String, Future[String]) => String{...}
```

or

```
 def getSomething: (String, Future[String])(implicit e: ExecutionContext) => String{...}
```

But it not works. Is it possible to pass implicit parameter to function like this? Or could I do it in other way?

Comment: Saying "it not works" is not enough, add error messages to your question. `def getSomething (implicit e: ExecutionContext): ... = ...` should work.

Comment: What is `if (name == "Joe", surname.map(s => s == "Doe"))`? `if` accepts `Boolean`, not tuple.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58381138/how-to-make-implicits-available-to-inner-function/

Comment: A function that receives a **Future** and doesn't return one is a code smell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def getSomething (implicit e: ExecutionContext): (String, Future[String]) => String = ...
```

should work.

You can't write

```
(String, Future[String]) => (implicit e: ExecutionContext) => String
```

Implicit functions will appear in Scala 3.

http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/context-functions.html

http://dotty.epfl.ch/blog/2016/12/05/implicit-function-types.html

Answer (score 2):

In Scala 3 we could return a function with implicit parameter, for example

```
def getSomething: ExecutionContext ?=> Future[String] => Future[Int] = {
  (using ec: ExecutionContext) => (f: Future[String]) => f.map(_.toInt)
}

given fiveThreadsEc as ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5))
getSomething(Future("42"))
```

Note how `?=>` in function type corresponds to `using` in function literal. Consider the example from [Change to `(using x: T) => E` for context functions #8305](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/8305)

```
val f: Int ?=> Int = (using x: Int) => 2 * x
f(using 2)
```